# Iterating through a dataframe and calculating a number based on columns and conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to solve a problem that wants me to calculate the expected shares of a company after several trades. The number of shares will start at 100 and then depending on whether or not the trade is a buy or sell, the calculation will either add or subtract. One caveat to the problem is that if the trade "counterparty" is BnL, the iteration should not use the row in its calculation.

I am attaching a picture of the dataframe here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mbHU.jpg

so far I've tried the following but have been having alot of trouble regarding the BnL caveat:

```
Quantity_IBM_Crest_822 = 100
for index, row in Quantity_IBM_Crest_822.iterrows():
    if row['Buy/Sell'] == 'B':
        Quantity_IBM_Crest_822 = Quantity_IBM_Crest_822 + row['Quantity']
    else:
        Quantity_IBM_Crest_822 = Quantity_IBM_Crest_822 - row['Quantity']        
print(Quantity_IBM_Crest_822)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Pandas data frame or series methods and not general purpose Python involving loops across rows:

```
sub_df = IBM_Crest_822.query("Counterparty != 'BnL Corp.'")

Quantity_IBM_Crest_822 = 100 + sum(sub_df['Buy/Sell'] == "B") + \
                               -1*sum(sub_df['Buy/Sell'] == "S")
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to disregard `BnL Corp.` trades, so first we can get quantities replacing values where `Counterparty` is `BnL Corp.` with zeroes. Then we multiply these values by -1 whenever `Buy/Sell` is `S`. And, finally, we calculate cumulative sum with `cumsum`, adding the initial value of 100:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Buy/Sell': ['B','B','B','B','S','B','B','B','S','S'],
                   'Quantity': [50, 100, 80, 20, 20, 150, 110, 200, 200, 40],
                   'Counterparty': ['M', 'M', 'BnL Corp.', 'A', 'A', 'BnL Corp.', 'BnL Corp.', 'BnL Corp.', 'M', 'A']})

x = df['Quantity'] * (df['Counterparty'] != 'BnL Corp.')
x.loc[df['Buy/Sell']=='S'] *= -1
df['CumQuantity'] = x.cumsum() + 100

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Buy/Sell  Quantity Counterparty  CumQuantity
0        B        50            M          150
1        B       100            M          250
2        B        80    BnL Corp.          250
3        B        20            A          270
4        S        20            A          250
5        B       150    BnL Corp.          250
6        B       110    BnL Corp.          250
7        B       200    BnL Corp.          250
8        S       200            M           50
9        S        40            A           10
```

If you're only interested in the resulting quantity:

```
x.sum() + 100
```

Output:

```
10
```

**Note:** Here's also a one-liner for the overall sum:

```
100 + sum(df['Quantity']*(2*(df['Buy/Sell']=='B')-1)*(df['Counterparty']!='BnL Corp.'))
```

Output:

```
10
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I run the code, the quantity is just accumulating and not subtracting any shares that may have been sold. Therefore, I keep getting an answer of 550.. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Hm, 550 is really odd, if I add `S` trades instead of subtracting them I get 530. Could it be that the values in the DataFrame are actually different from what we see in the screenshot?

Comment: The 550 is as a result of the BnL trades also being included.

Comment: Oh, right, so I used `BnL` in my example, but it's `BnL Corp.` in the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Derive a new DataFrame that does not contain trades having BnL in the `Counterparty` column.

```
withoutBnLDf = IBM_Crest_822[IBM_Crest_822['Counterparty'] != 'Bnl Corp.']
```

Furthermore, you should use `.iterrows()` when attempting to iterate over the rows of a DataFrame.

```
Quantity_IBM_Crest_822 = 100
for index, row in withoutBnLDf.iterrows():
    if row['Buy/Sell'] == 'B':
        Quantity_IBM_Crest_822 = Quantity_IBM_Crest_822 + row['Quantity']
    else:
        Quantity_IBM_Crest_822 = Quantity_IBM_Crest_822 - row['Quantity']        
print(Quantity_IBM_Crest_822)
```